# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble with posting to my API and can't quite figure out what the error is referring to. If it matters, I'm using Django REST and included the traceback.

```
if (repeat == false) {
    post_data = {'User': usernameInput}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/0/addUser',
        data: post_data,
        async: true
    })
}

class AddUser(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format = None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.isvalid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Error showing for this code:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  403.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  400.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rae/Desktop/112/djangotemplate/notes/views.py" in post
  23.       serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in __getattr__
  436.         return getattr(self._request, attr)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django REST Framework has its own `Request` object that wraps the `HttpRequest` object passed in by Django and adds some additional functionality (like custom rendering and another authentication layer). If any properties are accessed on the `Request` object that don't exist, it will automatically proxy it to the underlying `HttpRequest`, so typically you don't notice the difference.

In DRF 2.x, the `Request` property has `DATA` and `FILES` properties that store the passed in data as well as any files which have been detected. These were combined in DRF 3.0 and replaced with a single `data` property. As DRF 3.0 has been released, all of the documentation now reflects the new `Request.data` property.

You appear to be using Django REST Framework 2.x, but you are trying to access the new property introduced in DRF 3.0. Because it doesn't exist on the `Request` object, it is being proxied down to the `HttpRequest` object, where it also isn't being found.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.4 and am getting the same error. I'm using a middleware to store the request for debugging and in `process_response` trying to call `request.data` gives me the `no attribute 'data'` error. Ideas?

Comment: I'm using DRF 3.5.3 with djangorestframework-jwt 1.9.0 and also seeing this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Apparently this answer is incorrect for modern Django versions

Answer (score 10):

If you're experiencing this issue with a view method then you could try using the `@api_view` decorator

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(["POST"])
def Function(request, <other-stuff>):
    # do the thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Serializers need a drf request, but the request you have is a WSGIRequest provided by django.

I use the following function to retrieve the request.

```py
from django.http import HttpRequest
from rest_framework.request import Request

def preprocess_request(request):
    if isinstance(request, HttpRequest):
        return Request(request, parsers=[FormParser])
    return request
```

You might want to use a separate parser or provide multiple. My issue was slightly different and only requires FormParser!

Comment: context_parser and other required parameters are missing and create problems. like request = parser_context['request']
KeyError: 'request'