# Can't send data back to Django from JS AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

html-javascript

```
    var csrftoken = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();

    $('#Save').click(function () {

        var ajaxdata = {
            exam: $('#Exam').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/save',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(ajaxdata),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            success: function () {
                alert(ajaxdata);
                console.log(ajaxdata);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(ajaxdata);
            }
        });
    }
```

views.py

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def save(request=request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)

    testexam = data['exam']
    testexam = request.POST.get('exam')
    testobj = MyObject.objects.filter(name="David").first()
    testobj.Exam = testexam
    testobj.save()

return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success": True}), content_type="application/json")
```

These are my html and views now.

Removed the "flask" part.

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

allowed me to receive data successfully!

Still don't quite understand why " request.POST " didn't work.

I'll come back later to update if I manage to know the reason!

Thanks for the comments and useful suggestions!

Comment: Read what [403 means](https://httpstatuses.com/403). You may need to check the server configuration. If server requires some kind of authorization of the client, the client must pass this check.

Comment: @31piy so the code above looks fine to you?

Comment: You need to read [the docs on setting the token in Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) more closely. All you do there in your `ajaxSetup` is define an object, you don't do anything with it or add it to the POST at all. You'd be better off just putting that value into the `ajaxdata` object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006988/ajax-request-not-working-properly-in-django/51009944#51009944

Comment: @Wariored thanks for the link!
error 403 gone!
but "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" showed up... =(

Comment: This mostly happens when the view doesn't send back a correct json response. Show your views.py

Comment: @Wariored I thought the view is to "get" the json data?

Comment: import json and django  HttpResponse then to return this **return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success": True}), content_type="application/json")**

Comment: in your ajax your success function takes an argument (i.e data), try: console.log(data) in show what you have

Comment: @Wariored I followed your suggestion and it successfully returned success! But I still can't use the data I sent. See the edit above. Thanks for your patience. =)

Comment: Remove the Flask code. Your problem is not related to Flask and please accept your answer as the good one so people can benefit of it

Comment: @Wariored I've updated my post and accepted my answer. Thanks for your help. without it I can't achieve this! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need using the flask.

This is how I receive the data:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

and it all works well!

Thanks for all the comments, suggestions, answers! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

your ajax code is just fine, however you're doing few things wrong. First of all, in your html part.

```
<h1> This is simple html</h1>

<input type="text" id = "Exam">
<button type="button" id="Save">Save</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var csrftoken = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();



    $('#Save').click(function () {
        var ajaxdata = {
        exam: $('#Exam').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/save',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(ajaxdata),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            success: function () {
                alert(ajaxdata)
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log("this is an error")
            }
        });
    });

  </script>
```

You were initiating the ajaxdata before the click event happened, which may lead to the null value of `#Exam` filed.

Now getting back to your Flask part, you can't do request.POST with the data sent through Ajax request. Rather you can access all the data you sent through your js with request.data, below is the code which is working successfully.

```
from flask import Flask, request,send_from_directory
import json
# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def root():
    #return "this is home"
    return send_from_directory("/home/ekbana/Documents/","index.html")


@app.route('/save',methods=['POST'])
def save(request=request):
    print(request.data.decode("utf-8")) #We need to decode because it's a byte
                                        #not a string
    data = json.loads(request.data.decode("utf-8"))
    #data here is {'exam': 'a text'} a dict in this case
    testexam = data["exam"]
    testobj = MyObject.objects.filter(name="David").first()
    testobj.Exam = testexam
    testobj.save()

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"success": True}), content_type="application/json")
```

This is working fine with me, I replicated a simple example for your requirement. Aslo make sure to use methods=["POST"] if you want your route to recieve the POST request, if you didn't specify it, it may lead to HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.

Comment: Looks like I missed a lot of things! I followed your suggestion and edited my code(see above). I don't quite understand the "flask" part and keeps getting error 500. =(

Comment: Just comment out everything below the, data and type printing `print(data)`. It's because the model may not have been intialized, like in my case, I've not imported any MyObject as I don't have them.

Comment: I recieved [ AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data' ] at views.py " print(request.data.decode("utf-8")) "

Comment: try just `request` instead of `request=request`.

Comment: Please remove the request params from the method itself, and see. Weird, the request.data should give you the contained data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287852/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-data

Comment: could it be the same problem as the link above?

Comment: Can you please run your application in flask dev server like `flask run` after you export the FLASK_APP and FLASK_DEBUG variables? Or are you already doing the same?

Comment: sorry...i'm new to this, don't know how to do that =(