# How to merge two HTML buttons for a Flask website?

Tags: python, html, button, flask

I am building a website in python and I want to be able to start and stop the "`motiondetect.py`" through a single button. (Merge the two buttons)
Right now I have two separate "**Start motiondetect**" and "**Stop motiondetect**" buttons. I would like to have the **merged*** button start the motion detection the first time you click and the second click should stop it.

Here are my code snippets:

Python Start:

```
@app.route("/start", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def start_motion():
    global proc
    #global FNULL
    #global APP_ROOT
    print(" > Start")
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "motiondetect.py"])#, stdout=FNULL, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(" > Process id {}".format(proc.pid))
    return "Start Detection"
```

Html Start:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#start_button").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({type: "POST",
url: "/start",
data: {},
success:function(result){
  $("#start_button").html(result);
}});
      });

    });
```

Python Stop:

```
@app.route("/stop", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def stop_motion():
    global proc
    print(" > Stop")
    proc.kill()
    #os.system("echo > close")
    #print(" > Process killed")
    #time.sleep(2)
    #os.system("rm close")
    return "Stop Detection"
```

Html Stop:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#stop_button").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({type: "POST",
url: "/stop",
data: {},
success:function(result){
  $("#stop_button").html(result);
}});
      });
```

Thanks for your time and sory for my ignorance.

Comment: You probably need to store the state of button click somewhere, probably in frontend, say when a user click the button for the first time, you should have a state saved `first` and when the user click it again then you shall have a state `second` so that you could kill the process subsequently, that user has clicked the button second time. Also you could change the text in the button, initally it could be `start` and once the user click `start`, the text can be dynamically changed as `stop`.

Comment: @user2906838 I guess you'r right. I'm really new to web developing so forgive me but how would I store it in frontend. As a variable in python? Could you give me an example if it isn't asking too much ? Regardless thank you !

Comment: Ok, let me prepare a solution for you then.

Comment: I've written an example for you, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, For your ease I've produced an example to brief you the ideas. So here's what you can do on your Flask part.

```
from Flask import request
@app.route("/start", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def start_motion(request):
    global proc
    #global FNULL
    #global APP_ROOT
    data = json.loads(request.data.decode("utf-8"))
    #data here is {'exam': 'a text'} a dict in this case
    state = data["state"]
    if (state and state=="start"):
        print(" > Start")
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "motiondetect.py"])#, stdout=FNULL, 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
        print(" > Process id {}".format(proc.pid))
        return "Start Detection"

    else:
        print("the state is blank or is not requesting to start")

@app.route("/stop", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def stop_motion(request):
    global proc
    print(" > Stop")
    data = json.loads(request.data.decode("utf-8"))
    #data here is {'exam': 'a text'} a dict in this case
    state = data["state"]
    if (state and state=="start"):
        proc.kill()
    #os.system("echo > close")
    #print(" > Process killed")
    #time.sleep(2)
    #os.system("rm close")
    else:
        print("state is either blank or not stop")
    return "Stop Detection"
```

I simply added the code to receive the `state` data from the Ajax call and proceed in the backend.

Coming to your Html and Javascript side, this is what you can do:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#motion_button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    state = $(this).attr('value'); 
    if(state=="start")
    {
        $("#motion_button").attr("value")= "stop";
        $("#motion_button").text("Stop")
        callurl="/start"
    }
    elseif(state=="stop")
    {
        $("#motion_button").attr("value")= "start";
        $("#motion_button").text("Start")
        callurl="/stop"
    }


    $.ajax({type: "POST",
    url: "/start",
    data: {"state":state},
    success:function(result){
      $("#start_button").html(result);
    }});
     });

    });
```

Since you're using `POST` method to send the data, you may have to consider sending the `csrf` token as well. I hope you understand the frontend codes as they are pretty much straight forward. Also for reference, please check my answer [Can't send data back to Django from JS AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493940/cant-send-data-back-to-django-from-js-ajax/51511011#51511011) which contains a full example.

Comment: Thank you a bunch for the answer, your awsome ! Still don't have it working, but you put me on the right path. Let me do a little more research and i will get back to you !!!

Comment: Fine, that was the idea. Also you can tell further what exactly didn't work. The above code is for example purpose.